# How to get last 1 month data from today in sql?

Tags: sql

```
$sql = " SELECT  *  
         FROM user_claim_tag 
         LEFT JOIN tasks ON user_claim_tag.task_id = tasks.id 
         LEFT JOIN users ON user_claim_tag.user_id = users.uid 
         LEFT JOIN user_details ON user_details.usr_id = users.uid 
         WHERE ((user_claim_tag.complete = 'Y' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N')
         OR  (user_claim_tag.complete = 'NS'  AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') AND  complete_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() AND date_sub(  CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY complete_dt desc ";


         $ex = $this->db->query($sql);

         $data['data']  = $ex->result();
```

Comment: If you want a SQL answer, please post SQL code only, not some SQL query hidden in PHP (?) code.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

```
     Change your date between  first date_sub and then CURDATE()
      $sql = " SELECT  *  
     FROM user_claim_tag 
     LEFT JOIN tasks ON user_claim_tag.task_id = tasks.id 
     LEFT JOIN users ON user_claim_tag.user_id = users.uid 
     LEFT JOIN user_details ON user_details.usr_id = users.uid 
     WHERE ((user_claim_tag.complete = 'Y' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N')
     OR  (user_claim_tag.complete = 'NS'  AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') AND  complete_dt BETWEEN date_sub (CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))AND  CURDATE() ORDER BY complete_dt desc ";


     $ex = $this->db->query($sql);

     $data['data']  = $ex->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always Between and And will takes from smallest value to highest, so give last month time interval in between condition and then curdate()

// Your Query

```
$sql = " SELECT  *  
     FROM user_claim_tag 
     LEFT JOIN tasks ON user_claim_tag.task_id = tasks.id 
     LEFT JOIN users ON user_claim_tag.user_id = users.uid 
     LEFT JOIN user_details ON user_details.usr_id = users.uid 
     WHERE ((user_claim_tag.complete = 'Y' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N')
     OR  (user_claim_tag.complete = 'NS'  AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') AND  complete_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() AND date_sub(  CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY complete_dt desc ";
```

// changed query

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM user_claim_tag 
LEFT JOIN tasks ON user_claim_tag.task_id = tasks.id 
LEFT JOIN users ON user_claim_tag.user_id = users.uid 
LEFT JOIN user_details ON user_details.usr_id = users.uid 
WHERE ((user_claim_tag.complete = 'Y' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') 
OR (user_claim_tag.complete = 'NS' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') 
AND complete_dt BETWEEN date_sub( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY complete_dt desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work:

```
SELECT  *  
     FROM user_claim_tag 
     LEFT JOIN tasks ON user_claim_tag.task_id = tasks.id 
     LEFT JOIN users ON user_claim_tag.user_id = users.uid 
     LEFT JOIN user_details ON user_details.usr_id = users.uid 
     WHERE ((user_claim_tag.complete = 'Y' AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N')
     OR  (user_claim_tag.complete = 'NS'  AND tasks.is_deleted = 'N') AND 
     complete_dt BETWEEN GETDATE() AND  DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
     ORDER BY complete_dt desc ";
```